# How to install MapServer and MapCache on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: mapserver, ubuntu, mapcache

I want to install MapServer and MapCache on Ubuntu 14.04. The MapServer installation succeeded but now I'm stuck with the installation of MapCache. This is what I did so far:

Install MapServer and MapCache:

```
sudo apt-get install cgi-mapserver mapcache-cgi libapache2-mod-mapcache
```

Store my raster images in /mapserver/data/tamale_2014ds.tif and tamale_2014ws.tif and create a map file in /mapserver/tamale.map:

```
MAP
  PROJECTION
   "init=epsg:3857"
  END  
  IMAGETYPE      JPEG
  EXTENT         -94018 1048833 -92362 1049470
  SIZE           1000 400
  WEB
    METADATA
      "wms_title" "tamale"
  "wms_srs" "epsg:3857"
    END
  END
  LAYER
    METADATA
      "wms_title" "dry_season_2014"
      "wms_srs" "epsg:3857"
      "wms_enable_request" "*"
    END
    NAME         dry_season_2014
    DATA         /mapserver/data/tamale_2014ds.tif
    STATUS       OFF
    TYPE         RASTER
    PROCESSING   "BANDS=1,2,3"
    OFFSITE      0 0 0
  END 
  LAYER
    METADATA
      "wms_title" "wet_season_2014"
      "wms_srs" "epsg:3857"
      "wms_enable_request" "*"
    END
    NAME         wet_season_2014
    DATA         /mapserver/data/tamale_2014ws.tif
    STATUS       OFF
    TYPE         RASTER
    PROCESSING   "BANDS=1,2,3"
    OFFSITE      0 0 0
  END 
END
```

So far, everything is fine, see OpenLayers demo: http://geocre.net/mapservertest/ ([code](http://pastebin.com/5SFZY9iH))

For MapCache I edited my apache configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
<IfModule mapcache_module>
   <Directory /mapcache>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
   MapCacheAlias /mapcache "/mapcache/mapcache.xml"
</IfModule>
```

However, I cannot access MapCache. All I get is a status 403 Forbidden: `http://78.47.251.2/mapcache`

I already tried several owners and permissions for the directory /mapcache (even CHMOD 777). Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I think I found it: As I'm running Apache 2.4.7, the Apache configuration needs to look like this (see [here](http://mapserver.org/mapcache/install.html#apache-module-specific-instructions)):

```
<IfModule mapcache_module>
   <Directory /mapcache>
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
   MapCacheAlias /mapcache "/mapcache/mapcache.xml"
</IfModule>
```

The MapCache request URL is then `http://78.47.251.2/mapcache/?`. In OpenLayers, it is accessible like this:

```
var rasterLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Tamale (2014 WS)", "http://78.47.251.2/mapcache/?", {layers: 'tamale'} );
```