# How to make MapServer only accessible via MapCache?

Tags: mapserver, mapcache

I installed MapServer and MapCache on Ubuntu (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123958/how-to-install-mapserver-and-mapcache-on-ubuntu-14-04)). Now I would like to prevent the direct access to MapServer - requests should only be allowed via MapCache. I thought I could achieve this by accessing MapServer via localhost (in mapcache.xml / source) and allowing MapServer to only serve to localhost. The former works fine, but how to allow MapServer only serving to localhost?

Comment: This is not a MapServer nor GIS question. It is all about configuring security settings of Apache http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html. Deny from all - Allow from localhost should work for you.

Comment: I already tried that, but it had no effect.

Comment: How it did not have an effect? Despite deny from all you are still seeing the server from outside? Did you reload Apache?

Comment: Yes, I reloaded Apache. I added
<Directory "/mapserver">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Directory>
to the Apache configuration. MapServer is still accessible: http://78.47.251.2/cgi-bin/mapserv

Comment: I would suppose that mapserver is in directory /cgi-bin but I am no Apache master. They are in the main stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks, that points in the right direction! The directory is actually /usr/lib/cgi-bin. However, MapCache is also in that directory so it gets also blocked when disallowing the web access.

Comment: So you will need some more fine-grained Apache access control. It is for sure doable but unfortunately I do not know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out (thanks to user30184):

```
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
 <Files mapserv>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from localhost
 </Files>
</Directory>
```